# Watch multiple contracts/events?

Tags: solidity, dapp-development, javascript, events

Is there a way to watch events from multiple contracts with just one watch-statement (something like `[contract1.event, contract2.event, ...].watchAll()` ) in Javascript?

Code is just for illustration purposes:

```
   var event = contract.EventName({from: address}); // watching multiple contracts/events possible?
   event.watch(function(err, result) {
         ...
   });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a build in function to listen all the events in one watch statement

```
var events = myContractInstance.allEvents([additionalFilterObject]);

// watch for changes
events.watch(function(error, result){
  if (!error)
    console.log(result);
});
```

`additionalFilterObject` can used to filter the results; example adding an address would be `{address: myAddress}`

On the other hand doesn't seems possible to filter the events using the names unless you specify the topics on the `additionalFilterObject` where the topic addresses are the event/function hash (keccak256 of your event name eg. `keccak256('EventName1(uint)')`) then you would have something like:

```
var events = myContractInstance.allEvents({address: myAddress, topics: [['0x1234...', '0x5678...']]});

// watch for changes
events.watch(function(error, result){
  if (!error)
    console.log(result);
});
```

but you can check the event result and filter the event name according to the events you want to listen:

```
var events = myContractInstance.allEvents([additionalFilterObject]);

// watch for changes
events.watch(function(error, result){
  if (!error) {
    if(['EventName1', 'EventName2'].includes(result.event)) {
       //do
    }
  }
});
```

and that would be more readable maybe. Another less elegant solution could be

```
var event1 = contract.EventName1({from: address});
var event2 = contract.EventName2({from: address});
event1.watch(myCallback);
event2.watch(myCallback);

function myCallback(err, result) {
}
```

Comment: Thanks for answering, I'll take from it, that it is not possible watching different contracts and their events (just all events from one contract respectively).

Comment: sorry I misunderstood your question. I read it too quick and I find out just now that you was talking about different contracts. In that case you might take a look at web3.eth.filter. Maybe it can helps you https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/JavaScript-API#web3ethfilter

Answer (score 0):

method allEvents() will not work for `"web3": "^1.0.0-beta.36".` This will throw an error

```
allEvents is not a function
```

This will not work even for some other versions. Refer here
https://github.com/ethereum/web3.js/issues/989
It didnt work for me as well, I am using "web3": "^1.0.0-beta.36". If someone has an alternative, do share.