# Listening for events in a React DApp

Tags: solidity, web3js, react

I am new to React and don't know where I should put the code to `.watch()` for Solidity events.

Right now, I the code in a member function of my main App class. As is, I am successfully capturing events emitted by my contract ... but only when the page loads.

My goal is to subscribe to events so that I can log them as soon as they occur, but with React, I'm not sure where the proper place to put that code would be:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import AttendanceData from '../build/contracts/AttendanceData.json';
import getWeb3 from './utils/getWeb3';


class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      contract: null,
      name: "",
      storageValue: 0,
      eventId: 0,
      currentEventValue: 0,
      hasContributed: false,
      isLoggedIn: false,
      loggedInAddress: "",
      web3: null
    }
  }


  componentDidMount() {
    getWeb3
    .then(results => {
        this.setState({
            web3: results.web3
        })
        const contract = require('truffle-contract');
        const attendanceData = contract(AttendanceData);
        attendanceData.setProvider(this.state.web3.currentProvider);
        this.setState({contract: attendanceData});
        attendanceData.Contributed({}, {fromBlock: 1, toBlock: 'latest'});
        contributedEvent.watch(function(error, result) {
            if(!error){
                console.log("Event captured:", result);
            }
            else{
                console.log("Error capturing event:", error);
            }
        });
    })
    .catch(() => {
      console.log('Error finding web3.')
    })
  }

  contribute() {
    const attendanceData = this.state.contract;

    // Declaring this for later so we can chain functions on AttendanceData.
    var attendanceDataInstance;

    // Get accounts.
    this.state.web3.eth.getAccounts((error, accounts) => {
      attendanceData.deployed().then((instance) => {
        attendanceDataInstance = instance;
        // Stores a given value, 5 by default.
        return attendanceDataInstance.contribute({value: this.state.web3.toWei(this.state.amountToContribute, 'ether'), gasPrice: 2000000000, gas: 300000, from: accounts[0]})
      }).then((result) => {
        console.log("Was successful: "+result);
      }).catch((err) => {
        console.log("Failed with error: " + err);
      });
    })
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <button onClick={this.contribute}>CONTRIBUTE!</button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
let event = contractInstance.event()
event.watch(callback)
```

Working example in an onClick function:

https://gist.github.com/kyriediculous/13efccc780a9c180b37f4c27fe696bb8#file-methods-js

This is in Vuejs but it's very similar: https://itnext.io/create-your-first-ethereum-dapp-with-web3-and-vue-js-part-3-dc4f82fba4b4

In this example I have defined a reactive variable in the data() property, when the event fires this variable will update and the dom will re-render with the event.

Comment: Looking at your snippet, I'm guessing this returns to you every single Won() event from all blocks? I have set something like this up, but each time I trigger the method, it returns back the full history of that event. Will have to filter these results. Thanks!

Comment: Since I'm only listening for events when sending a transaction it only returns the event for the user sending the transaction. At least , I haven't tested it with multiple tx being sent in the same block to the contract.

Comment: You can probably also use web3.eth.filter('latest', ... ) , that watchest the last block.

Answer (score -1):

You can use `componentDidMount` inside your React component:

```
class MyCPT extends React.Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    // your code here
  }
}
```

> componentDidMount() is invoked immediately after a component is mounted. Initialization that requires DOM nodes should go here. If you need to load data from a remote endpoint, this is a good place to instantiate the network request.

https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#componentdidmount

Comment: Thanks! I did that. But unfortunately I'm only seeing the events come in when I refresh the page. How would I have this subscribe to all events as they come in live?

Comment: can you update your post with the new code of your component ?

Comment: hi @mirg , i have updated my original post with my code (tried to remove unnecessary parts).

Comment: `contributedEvent` is not defined and the syntax is wrong. `myContractInstance.MyEvent(callback);` is the right syntax. In your case the contract instance is `attendanceDataInstance`. https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/JavaScript-API#contract-events or https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/42539/watch-multiple-contracts-events/42563#42563